# Как правильно организовать хранение прикрепленных файлов?

Tags: веб-программирование, файлы, хранение-данных

Есть CKEditor + Elfinder, допустим, пользователь при отправке сообщения может прикрепить файлы и фото. Как лучше организовать хранение этих файлов? Нужна возможность ограничить общий размер загружаемых файлов, удалять эти файлы при удалении сообщения.

Comment: @entermix, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Ограничение размера загружаемых файлов в php.conf и в настройках Вашего приложения (в котором используется CKEditor).
Обычно приложения имеют проверку на предмет "потерявшихся" картинок (как, например, IPBoard).
Хранить в uploads.